# Div height is messing up

Tags: css, height, containers

I have a div that I basically want to stretch over the whole viewport.

When zoomed out its perfect, as you can see the black background is covering all the viewport:

[image: height is perfect, it fills the screen!]

When I zoom in to about 150-175% the height messes up, leaving the background behind it visible. Which is not what I want, see the bottom of the image:

[image: see bottom of image, height messes up, does not fill document height]

Is there an easy solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="x_all">

</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#x_all{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, .9);
    z-index: 399;
}
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? Each browsers zooming behaviour is different. Maybe try setting body width and height to 100% but that's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using position: absolute

Instead add

position: fixed;

and don't forget to add

left: 0px;

otherwise you'll have a white gap to the left of the page.

Comment: Thanks Ned! Mind was going nuts, knew it was something simple!

Comment: Good luck on your project :)